# In ES2015, how do you reconstruct a tagged template literal in the correct order?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, tagged-templates

Using the example from the MDN docs on template literals, we can create custom "tag" functions.

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

function tag(strings, ...values) {
    console.log(strings[0]);
    console.log(strings[1]);
    console.log(values[0]);
    console.log(values[1]);

    return strings[0] + ' ' + values[0] + ' ' + strings[1] + ' ' + values[1];
}

tag`Hello ${ a + b } world ${ a * b }`;
```

From here, how do we construct the message in the same order it was fed in when mixing `strings` with `values`?

The above tag function would fail to maintain order when swap the value/string order, such as:

```
tag`Hello ${ a + b } world ${ a * b }`;
// swapped to
tag`${ a + b } hello ${ a * b } world`;
```

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strings.length` will always be greater than `...values.length` by one. The first value of `strings` will always be the content of the template string up to the first substitution. When a substitution is the first value of the template string, `strings[0]` is an empty string. The same goes for when the last value of the template string is a substitution, `strings[strings.length-1]` is an empty string.

So in your example, you output the empty string as `strings[0]` and `strings[1]` becomes `hello`, but you never output `strings[2]` for `world`. The correct way to rejoin the strings is to assign the first index of `strings` to a string, then loop over all the values and add them together in order.

```
function tag(strings, ...values) {
  var str = strings[0];
  for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    str += values[i] + strings[i+1];
  }

  return str;
}
```

Comment: Ah...! That's cool - can I get a reference on the "first value of strings will always be empty"? -- I just couldn't find it documented anywhere

Comment: I'm not sure there's a hard reference anywhere. I think I discovered it through trial and error.

Comment: _"I'm not sure there's a hard reference anywhere."_ Everything has to be covered by the language specification in the end. Section 12.2.9 describes this behavior.

Comment: A better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44254377/