# How to call native es6 template string replacement from tag function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variadic-templates, template-literals

I'm writing a es6 tag function for template literals, which first checks a condition in the string and, if the condition isn't found, merely interprets the template literal as if it were untagged. I am curious if, from my tag function, there is a way to call the browser's native template literal function (which I assume would be faster than **my own implemented function**). Bonue: With this, couldn't there be an opportunity for tag composition, eg htmlEscape(unindent`foobar`);

eg.

```
function dumbTag(strs, ...vals) {
    vals = vals.map((val,i) =>
            (i % 2 == 0 ? 'even:' : 'odd:')+val);
    return String.template(strs, ...vals);
}
```

**my own implemented function - is there a faster way / way to call what the browser does?**

```
function template(strs, ...vals) {
    let result = strs[0];
    for (let [i,val] of vals.entries()) {
        result += val;
        result += strs[i+1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a function to call... if you find one, let me know.

Comment: What's `substs`, did you mean `vals`?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, updated

Answer (score 14):

You can (ab)use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) (currently the only built-in tag) for this purpose:

```
function doNothingTag() {
  arguments[0] = { raw: arguments[0] };
  return String.raw(...arguments);
}

// Or in a more modern style:
const doNothingTag = (strings, ...rest) => String.raw({ raw: strings }, ...rest);

doNothingTag`It ${'works'}!`
// "It works!"

doNothingTag`Even\nwith\nescape\nsequences!`
// "Even
// with
// escape
// sequences!"
```

This is essentially just tricking `String.raw` into thinking that the escape-interpreted string is the raw version.

---

**March 2024 update:**

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-cooked) (currently at stage 1 in the process) for a "`String.cooked`" function to solve this more elegantly.

Comment: So, as long as you know for certain that you don't have any escape sequences in your templates, you can use `String.raw` "as is", i.e. `const tag = String.raw;`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such builtin function - untagged template literals are just evaluated straight to strings.

> is there a faster way?

That depends a lot on the implementation. In case you are using a transpiler, I would avoid using rest parameters, iterators and `for of` loops:

```
function template(strs) {
    var result = strs[0];
    for (var i=1; i < strs.length; i++) {
        result += arguments[i];
        result += strs[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also wondering if there is such a native function. In the meantime, this is what I use:

```js
const tag = ([head, ...tail], ...args) => tail.reduce((a, b, i) => a + args[i] + b, head);
```

Comment: `const tag = (strings, ...values) => values.reduce( (s, v, i, strings) => \`${s}${v}${strings[i + 1]}\`, strings[0] ); // A slightly shorter version`

Answer (score 0):

A short implementation could be done by using [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) like this:

```js
const defaultTag = (strs, ...vals) =>
  strs.flatMap((x, i) => [x, i < vals.length ? vals[i] : undefined]).join('');

const name = 'Some name';
const age = 32;

console.log(defaultTag`Hi my name is ${name}, and I'm ${age} years old!`);
```

Comment: This accesses an out-of-bounds index on `vals`. `.join()` ignores the resulting `undefined` value, but you still shouldn't do it.

Comment: Why shouldn't I? This behavior is consistent across browsers so it shouldn't be bug prone.

Comment: I'm not saying that it doesn't work, I'm saying that it's a bad practice and prevents compiler optimisations.

Comment: Does the compiler know that I'm going to access an out-of-bounds item at run time?

Comment: [Yes](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#avoid-reading-beyond-the-length-of-the-array).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've edited my answer