# Assemble a template string with a tagged template literals as normally

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, tagged-templates

I'm looking for a function that takes `strings` and `values` and assembles the template string as a normal untagged template literal would. Does this exist? What's the logic? What needs to go inside the `tag` function to make the test case be complete?

```
function tag(strings, ...values) {
  return ''
}

let example = soup

let one = tag`string text ${example} 1 string text line 2`
let two = `string text ${example} 1 string text line 2`

assert.equals(one, two)
```

Comment: I've asked a similar question before trying to get an answer for your question; In short, no there is not, but you can implement it yourself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209627/how-to-call-native-es6-template-string-replacement-from-tag-function